# Confusion over Multiple Matches in a Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I've tested my regex in a regex tester and the statement itself appears that it should be working, however instead of matching 4 objects as it should, it only matches 1 (the entire string) which I'm not sure why its even doing that...

```
rgx = new Regex(@"^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$");
matches = rgx.Matches("0.0.0.95");
```

at this point if I do:

```
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

it will just show "0.0.0.95" when it should be matching 0, 0, 0, and 95 and not the entire string. What am I doing wrong here?

ANSWER - The single match of the entire string contained the group matches I was looking for, accessed in this manner:

```
r.r1 = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value);
r.r2 = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[2].Value);
r.r3 = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[3].Value);
r.r4 = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[4].Value);
```

Comment: Search about group matching in MSDN.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you don't get multiple matches - there is only one match in there, but it has four *capturing groups*:

```
    ^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$
//   ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
//   Group  1  Group  2  Group  3  Group  4
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                Group 0
```

There is a special group number zero that includes the entire match.

So you need to modify your program like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("One:'{0}' Two:'{1}' Three:'{2}' Four:'{3}'"
,   m.Groups[1].Value
,   m.Groups[2].Value
,   m.Groups[3].Value
,   m.Groups[4].Value
);
```